# How to record mic input and an audio track on iPhone at the same time

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, mp3, m4a

I am looking to record and save a music/song file with one or more audio track(s) let's say a max of two tracks playing simultaneously while recording my vocals via the headset or the microphone. The finished product will be a single song file(mp3 or other format).

Also, the code should have the ability to filter out outside noise/interferance and add basic effects.

Appreciate any and all Xcode help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord.
in my code, played karaoke file in MPMoviePlayer and at same time takes input from mic.
output is audio from MPMoviePlayer and it will be used as input also + input from mic.
i started to save this input in caf file, and upon finish product should be single file.